# C# Returns Array Element (using ref)

Tags: c#, arrays

I made return array element program for my assignment.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] theArray;

        bringArray(out theArray);


        for (int i = 1; i < theArray.Length; i++)
        {
             Console.Write(theArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    static void bringArray(out int[] arr)
    {
        arr = new int[4] {18, 28, 38, 48};
    }
```

I have to Use 'Ref' to return the array but I just used 'Out'.
Can anyone help me how to use 'ref' for this code?

Also I need the output in separated lines.
(eg.

28

38

40)

Could you please help me to solve these problems?
Thank you

Comment: the difference between "out" and "ref" are minor. one states that the variable can be passed to a method argument without being assigned and the other must be assigned before being passed.

Comment: For your second problem, check for other methods on Console. `Write` isn't the only one that prints stuff to the console...

Comment: The idiomatic way of returning an array is using `return <put your array here>;` not `ref` nor `out`.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] theArray = null;

        bringArray(ref theArray);


        for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(theArray[i] + " ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void bringArray(ref int[] arr)
    {
        arr = new int[4] { 18, 28, 38, 48 };
    }
```

Comment: whoever doesn't like the code can you please point out what's wrong in the code ?? and it does exactly what the question is about ..

i know we can do it using return but what's wrong in this answer? we will discuss separately whats idiomatic or what's not

Comment: hey muhammad i did not down vote but why are you encouraging using a ref in a method like this? i know the OP asked but this is terrible code for no reason!

Comment: I know this is terrible, I just answered the question assuming this may be the assignment given in college/uni

Comment: yeah i understand but if that was the case i think the best mark would be doing it correctly! :)

Comment: what if the person needs to understand how ref and out works and then in professional environment he/she uses return

Comment: Actually this is about answering questions isn't it? Even though it probably isn't bad to point out additionally how it's done correctly.

Comment: I would at the very least add a bit of explanation here

Comment: yeah I agree with the explanation thing and i didn't include it as it's already there in the comment

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use any of them you can do this easily and a lot cleaner by using returns. To write a new line i would use `Environment.NewLine`.

Always think about the best and cleanest way to solve the issue! Hope it helps :)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] theArray = bringArray();
        for (int i = 1; i < theArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(theArray[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    static int[] bringArray()
    {
        return new int[4] { 18, 28, 38, 48 };
    }
```